# Using sqlSave function of RODBC package to save data into a table

Tags: r, rodbc

While trying to use `sqlSave` function of `RODBC`, I am not able to choose which database I want to create a table under a connection. I created a connection by name x in `MYSQL`. But, there are multiple databases in my `MYSQL` connnection. But, `sqlSave` doesnt let define the option of which database to choose to create a table from R. Can anyone please suggest if I am missing something or if there is any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting this. I was making some syntactical mistakes. Now, I am able to execute this.

Thanks!!